# ListSelectionListener null pointer error

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

I'm trying to get a specific color for a specific category display on my south JPanel but I get NullPointerExeception error. What am I doing wrong?

```
//This is the arrays holding the category names and colors.
```

Comment: what does the stacktrace tell you?

Comment: It points to the syd.setBackground(colors[kategoriLista.getSelectedIndex()]);

Comment: What could be null on that line? kategoriLista? syd?

Comment: I think it's the list, kategoriLista because I checked if it was null and it was

Comment: So now look back into your code and find out why.

Comment: But I can't understand why the list would be null...

Comment: ... nor can we based on what you've posted. You must look at where you ***think*** you've initialized and see why this did not initialize the variable that is in fact null. Use a debugger if need be, check to make sure that you're not shadowing variables.

Comment: then why would an array be null ?

Comment: You said that you tested `kategoriLista` and it was `null`, then why are you asking about the array? If you need further help, you will want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: A chit -- you're shadowing the colors array. This is why you need to run your code with a debugger! In the future, please show your stacktrace, please indicate which line throws the exception, please show all pertinent code.

Comment: Yes I need to learn that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking if the selected index in your list is greater than -1.

```
//This is the arrays holding the category names and colors.
String[] cati = {"Ingen", "Matställen", "Skolor", "Kyrkor", "Kollektiv trafik"};
Color[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.PINK};

// This is a inner class in the super class. 
class kategoriFärg implements ListSelectionListener {   
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

        if (kategorLista.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
            System.out.println("does this work?");
            syd.setBackground(colors[kategoriLista.getSelectedIndex()]);
            //syd is the south JPanel
        }
    }
}
```

-1 means that no item in your list is selected.  If your error occurs on the if statement, then kategorLista is null and needs to be initialized.  Your sample code, you provided, looks like you initialized it.  Otherwise, syd is null and needs to be initialized.

If all of that is running. Then in the code that you provided.

```
öst.add(kategoriLista);
```

Is `öst` initialized?  The error you're getting should have been pointing at the line of code that is causing the error.

### EDIT

Based on the extra code that you've added...  Make these two lines of codes class variables

```
String[] cati = { "Ingen", "Matställen", "Skolor", "Kyrkor",
        "Kollektiv trafik" };
Color[] colors = { Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW,
        Color.PINK };
```

You have them coded in the contructor and they cannot be seen anywhere else in the class.  If you already have them declared as class variables,  then in your constructor change the code to:

```
cati = { "Ingen", "Matställen", "Skolor", "Kyrkor",
        "Kollektiv trafik" };
colors = { Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW,
        Color.PINK };
```

I believe the name is call shadowing...  You original code, shadowed your class variables, and local variables were initialized instead of your class variables.

Comment: I would think that this wouldn't cause a NPE but rather would cause an AIOOBE.

Comment: @Nohamin: again, create and post your [minimal compilable, runnable example program](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree, but based on the commenting back and forth I see, the OP doesn't appear to be familiar with debugging.  Nonetheless, when dealing with valueChanged for JLists & JComboBoxes, checking that the selectedIndex > -1 should be used.

Comment: I agree with your statement above.

Comment: Yes, it worked know when i made the arrays to class variables! Thank u :)

Comment: @Nohamin You're welcome...  Kindly check my answer so your question is marked solved.